# How can I create cascading dependent drop-down menus in HTML using ajax calls to an API

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I apologize in advance for this question as it is likely to be very elementary, but I'm not well versed in any coding so I'm hoping to find help here.

I have been able to create a set of dependent cascading dropdown menus in html without passing data from ajax calls between the selections.

Now I'm trying to do the following:

I have a dropdown selection in HTML:

```
<div style="display:none" id="group-test1">
      <select name="test1" id="action_item_id" class="test1" onchange="selecttest1()">
      </select>
</div>
```

that gets its data from an ajax call:

```
function selecttest1() { invite_item_id = document.getElementById("action_item_id").value; }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                "url":api_base+"/selecttest1",
                "type":"GET",
                "contentType":"application/json",
                "success":function(data){
                  var s = '<option value="-1">Select a test1</option>';  
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
                        s += '<option value="' + data[i].test1_id + '">' + data[i].test1_name + '</option>';  
                        action_item_id = data[i].test1_id
                    }  
                    $("#action_item_id").html(s);
                  }  
              });  
          });
```

This produces a selection of a few test names and corresponding ids.

I now want to do create a second selection based on the id value of the first, so display the second set of options based on the first selection:

```
<div style="display:none" id="group-test2">
     <select name="test1" id="test1" class="test1" onchange="selecttest1()">       
     </select>
     </br>
     </br>
     <select name="test2" id="action_item_id" class="test2" onchange="selecttest2()">      
     </select>
</div>
```

for example if selecttest1 is a selection of car brands, and certain brands only allow certain colors, selecttest2 would only show the colors of the specific brand chosen in selecttest1's dropdown.

Does anyone have a suggestion where I might start?  I've been beating my head against the wall a bit too long on this one I fear.

Comment: A little broad for stack overflow. That being said what you need is a second AJAX call to another API that takes a parameter. Using GET you can just append the parameter to the querystring in the URL. Then you can basically recycle what you have for the initial dropdown.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try to work on this direction and report back as soon as I've either solved it or my head has another flat side!